# Move data from one array to another array in the same document

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to move an array element from one array to another array within the same document and delete the element from the original array it was moved from.

```
// Document
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000838f7a7"),
   persons: [
        {
           personId: "61cd90594947be000838f7c1",
           name: "John Doe",
           employment: [
               {
                  employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
                  type: "Full time",
                  salary: 1010101
               }
           ]
        },
        {
           personId: "61cd90594947be000838f7c2",
           name: "Jane Austin",
           employment: [
               {
                  employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000738f7c1",
                  type: "Part time",
                  salary: 11011111
               }
           ]
        },
   ]
}
```

I need to move one of the employment element from **John Doe** to **Jane Austin** and both of those persons are in the same document. And I need to delete that moved element from **John Doe**.
`employmentId` is used to identify which employment to move. And `personId` is used to identify from which person to move to which person.

**Example payload**

```js
const updatePayload = {
   fromPerson: "61cd90594947be000838f7c1",
   toPerson: "61cd90594947be000838f7c2",
   employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
// employment from John Doe is moved to Jane Austin
{
   _id: ObjectId("67dc90594947be000838f7a7"),
   persons: [
        {
           personId: "61cd90594947be000838f7c1",
           name: "John Doe",
           employment: [ ]
        },
        {
           personId: "61cd90594947be000838f7c2",
           name: "Jane Austin",
           employment: [
               {
                  employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000738f7c1",
                  type: "Part time",
                  salary: 11011111
               },
               {
                  employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
                  type: "Full time",
                  salary: 1010101
               }
           ]
        },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working sample for Mongo version 4.4, our strategy will be to first match the `employment` we want to move, then update each of the `persons` accordingly, I will say that doing this in Mongo v5.0+ will be much cleaner as we could use [$getField](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/), this would make the first two stages of the pipelined update much simpler.

With that said here is the code sample:

```
const updatePayload = {
   fromPerson: "61cd90594947be000838f7c1",
   toPerson: "61cd90594947be000838f7c2",
   employmentId: "61cd9059494abe000838f7c8",
}

db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      tmpPerson: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$persons",
              as: "person",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$person.personId",
                  updatePayload.fromPerson
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      tmpEmployment: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$tmpPerson.employment",
              as: "employment",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$employment.employmentId",
                  updatePayload.employmentId
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      persons: {
        $map: {
          input: "$persons",
          as: "person",
          in: {
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$person.personId",
                      updatePayload.fromPerson
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$person",
                      {
                        employment: {
                          $filter: {
                            input: "$$person.employment",
                            as: "employment",
                            cond: {
                              $eq: [
                                "$$employment.employmentId",
                                updatePayload.employmentId
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$person.personId",
                      updatePayload.toPerson
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$person",
                      {
                        employment: {
                          $concatArrays: [
                            "$$person.employment",
                            [
                              "$tmpEmployment"
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$person"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "tmpPerson",
      "tmpEmployment"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5RFejIgPlKm)

One last thing to note is that this pipeline assumes that the input exists properly, otherwise it will add `null` to the employment array. if this is not the case then you should add some protection.